# Question closed as Too Broad is likely answerable if inverted, should I make this edit myself?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233110/elemental-shaman-pvp) today that was closed as Too Broad and while given it's current state I agree it is too broad, I think if the question were certainly inverted it would become much more answerable.

I have posted a comment stating as much for the OP as well as providing a brief answer to hopefully push him into making the edit so a full answer could be given.

So my question is should I just go ahead and make this edit myself, or would reviewers see it has too big of a change?

Comment: No, because that would change the intent of the question. Wait a while to see if the OP comes back and makes that change. If they do not, you can post your own question.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Do not answer in a comment. Do not change the question being asked, unless it is your question. You are free to post the 'alternate question' as a separate question, providing it follows the rules of the Arqade.

---

First and foremost, **you should not post an answer in the comments**. This is bad form. I can give a couple of reasons behind this:

1 - The comment section is often overlooked when scrolling through. By having answers in answers and clarification in comments, we make it easier to identify the possible solutions.

2 - If your comment answers the question, there is a good chance OP won't put the effort in to reword their question. In this case, the OP is a new user, who **last logged in on the same day that the question was posted**. I try not to assume that new users are just going to 'dine and ditch' - we all start as new users, at some point - but in cases like this, the odds are not in our favour.

3 - If your answer adds merit, it would be easy to "hijack" your answer. You obviously have an amount of experience in context of the question - but if another user was to post the same information as an **answer**, your answer could then be removed for low quality, as it adds no additional content to what has already been posted.

---

Secondly, **if you change the question entirely, you change the intent of the question**. This is something OP would have to do. In essence, you interpret the question to ask for a list of spells that work in a given situation. That list is quite extensive, so instead, you support changing the question to ask for a list of spells that do not work in the same situation.

While it seems pretty obvious that you could derive a list of working spells from a list of non-working spells, we can not assume that that would still address the exact same problem. It probably will - but ultimately, that is OPs call to make, not ours.

---

Solution: Post your interpretation as a **separate question**, and answer it, yourself. Comment on the original question with 'related question [my question]'.

Comment: I figured as much, thank you for your information. I have posted a new question that will hopefully cover off this topic, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233902/in-pvp-are-there-any-debuffs-that-cannot-be-dispelled/233903#233903